# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl8.5.so

Tags: c, ld, eggdrop

I am trying to compile an eggdrop. 
I get through compile and try "make" but get /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl8.5.so

---------- Yeah! That's the compiling, now the linking! ----------

Linking eggdrop (standard build).

```
gcc -o ../eggdrop bg.o botcmd.o botmsg.o botnet.o chanprog.o cmds.o dcc.o dccutil.o dns.o flags.o language.o match.o main.o mem.o misc.o misc_file.o modules.o net.o rfc1459.o tcl.o tcldcc.o tclhash.o tclmisc.o tcluser.o userent.o userrec.o users.o  -L/usr/lib -ltcl8.5.so -lm -ldl -lnsl  md5/md5c.o compat/*.o `cat mod/mod.xlibs`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl8.5.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../eggdrop] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fubar/eggdrop1.6.21/src'
make: *** [modegg] Error 2
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the TCL development libraries installed?

Comment: yes I do. If I didn't I wouldn't even have been able to get this far.

Comment: Is there a `libtcl8.5.so` in `/usr/lib`? Who decided on `-ltcl8.5.so` rather than `-ltcl8.5`? Could be nothing but it looks a bit odd.

Comment: well I'm not sure where to change the name of the file that its looking for and I did a full system search and there is no ltcl8.5.so

Comment: `-lX` means look for `libX.so` so you should be looking for `libtcl8.5.so`.

Comment: Well I found it and now I am receiving

/usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so: undefined reference to `__fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15'
/usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../eggdrop] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fubar/eggdrop1.6.21/src'
make: *** [modegg] Error 2